# Convert to decimal and round up keeping 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have been working on a system for a while now, and the client has been testing it. They want the system to now Round up keeping two decimal places. Can someone help as i seem to be having trouble with `Math.Ceiling` and converting the numbers to decimal. My code is below.

Line 2 is where the change needs to be made and the figure needs to round up keeping 2 decimal places.

```
float fcharge = Convert.ToSingle(dr["total_charge_weight"]) * Convert.ToSingle(dr["H_unit_rate"]);
decimal dcharge = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(fcharge), 2);
float charge = Convert.ToSingle(dcharge);
```

Comment: can you provide a example with input and expected output data?

Comment: What is wrong with your code ?

Comment: @fubo input will be 123.877 expected output 123.90

Comment: Did you try to _decimal dcharge = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(fcharge), 1);_ ?

Comment: I have it just drops away numbers after the decimal until there is 1 or 2 left

Comment: Note that 123.90 is the same as 123.9 from the point of view of the decima/float variable. It is how you display it that makes the difference between 1 or 2 decimals. After rounding to 1 decimal then use ToString("N2") to show two decimals

Comment: @Steve the client is very specific that only the decimal is to either round up or drop away example 123.505 output 123.51 and 123.515 output 123.50,  the 5 will round up but the 2 will drop away.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this do?

```
 public static float RoundUp(float number, int decimalPlaces)
 {
     var scale = Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);
     return (float)(Math.Ceiling(number * scale) / scale);
 }
```

Things to consider:

1. You are required to roud *up*. `Math.Round` does not do that.
2. There is no need to use `Convert`, simply cast.
3. There is no need to convert to `decimal`, you are throwing it away when converting back to `float`; use the implicit conversion to `double` and only cast back to `float` if its a requirement.